# Unit Test failed when using Visual Studio Command Prompt

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, mstest, command-prompt

I have class library project which reads word document files.  and I have created 30 unit cases scenarios for it. When I run the unit test using visual studio IDE it runs perfectly and all the test cases get "Success", However when I use Visual Studio Command Prompt and test it, some of the test cases get failed. I would appreciate if you guys can provide me some hint in this regard.
To test my solution in Command Prompts I type: "MSTest /testcontainer:mysolutiontest.dll"

Comment: What version of visual studio are your running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are running VS2012 or later, use [vstest.console.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155796.aspx):

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   12.0\Common7\ide\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe"
>   PathToYour.dll /logger:trx

You'll also probably want to use a [`.runsettings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635153.aspx) file to specify the TargetPlatform and ResultsDirectory, which would then use a command line like this:

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   12.0\Common7\ide\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe"
>   PathToYour.dll /logger:trx
>   /settings:PathToYour.runsettings